# Error while sending build android CODENAMEONE

Tags: java, android, netbeans, codenameone

I'm trying to send a build of my project 2 times on android and it still doesn't show in the cloud server builds. I but it suddenly says
"Jar size limit reached for free accounts". I can't switch to pro since this is a school project. I'm using Netbeans, through a simulator. I made sure I'm logged in both the web server and the project settings but my account is FREE
[image]
[[image]]What I want is to achieve this so I could download my project in my device[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZb6P.png)

[[image: The project settings]]The project settings[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hMgZ.png)

Comment: From [the Codename One FAQs](https://www.codenameone.com/faq.html): **"_What are the limits of the free version?...there is a JAR size limit of 1mb_"**. So the solution to your problem is to create smaller jar files. If you are getting the error when your jar files are < 1mb then update your question accordingly. Otherwise there is no issue to be resolved.

Comment: This error should be printed to the console when you build, also notice that I mentioned the size limitation specifically when we discussed embedding the MP3 file in your jar. In case this isn't the issue also check out this post: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-fix-issue-missing-builds.html which is applicable if you use the plugin If you use Maven things should work fine